# osclass SQL Inserting data twice

Tags: php, osclass

i have this osclass table when I insert a data and then browse the table the data has been entered twice, so i get two id of the same table.

```
CREATE TABLE  /*TABLE_PREFIX*/t_table_log(
    pk_i_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
    fk_i_user_id INT NULL ,
    fk_i_item_id INT NULL ,
    s_email VARCHAR( 200 ) NULL ,
    s_status VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL ,

    PRIMARY KEY(pk_i_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET 'UTF8' COLLATE 'UTF8_GENERAL_CI';
```

this is my php code

```
$conn = getConnection();
$conn->osc_dbExec("INSERT INTO %st_table_log (fk_i_item_id, fk_i_user_id, s_email, s_status ) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['itemid']."','".$_SESSION['userid']."','".$response['senderEmail']."','".$response['status']."')", DB_TABLE_PREFIX) ;
$item_url =  osc_item_url() ;
    $name = osc_page_title() ;
    $subject = (__("Hello",'osclass'));
    $email = osc_logged_admin_email();
        $messagesend =" my message";
          $params = array(
            'subject' => $subject
            ,'to' => $email
            ,'to_name' =>$name
            ,'body' => $messagesend
            ,'alt_body' => strip_tags($messagesend)
       ) ;
        osc_sendMail($params) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Where's located your code?

You might want to check those things:

- **autocron:** this is an Osclass-feature that runs Cron without the need to configure the crontab. Head to `Settings > General` and check if autocron is checked. It makes a new HTTP request for it, so your code might be running twice.
- **ajax:** you might have some ajax query in one of your enabled plugins or theme that makes a request on each loading and run your code twice.

From what I see, you might want to use the `'init'` hook to be sure it gets executed once. Something like this:

```
osc_add_hook('init', function () {
  $session = Session::newInstance();
  $userId = $session->_get('userid');
  $itemId = $session->_get('itemid');

  // Do something.
});
```

Also, try to take a look at [DAO in Osclass](https://doc.osclass.org/How_to_upgrade_your_plugins_to_new_DAO_classes) and [plugin development](https://doc.osclass.org/How_to_create_a_plugin), here's [a tutorial that will get you through Osclass plugin development and the use of DAO](https://wearemadhouse.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/how-to-develop-osclass-plugins/).